# matplotlibの.colorbar()でカラーバーが表示されない

Tags: python, matplotlib

matplotlibの散布図のカラーマッピングにおいて，`plt.colorbar()`を散布図プロット後にしているのですが，そこで以下のエラーが発生し，描画できません．
以下のサイトを参考にしたのですが，，，

- [matplotlib で散布図 (Scatter plot) を描く](https://pythondatascience.plavox.info/matplotlib/%E6%95%A3%E5%B8%83%E5%9B%B3)
- [Matplotlibで3D Dataを2D color mapとしてプロットしたい - teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/140818)

一方で，`plt.colorbar()`をコメントアウトするとカラーバーが無い散布図のカラーマッピングが描画できます．

カラーバーを表示させる方法を教えてください．よろしくお願いいたします．

Pythonのグラフプロットのコードは以下
（`medi_paTV_lnaTV[][N, M]`のリストは，`len(paTVarr) == N`，`len(lnaTVarr) == M`の2次元配列）

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
# ========= カラー散布図を描画 =========
for i, item in enumerate(medi_paTV_lnaTV[0]):
    ax.scatter(np.full(len(paTVarr), paTVarr[i]).tolist(), lnaTVarr, c=medi_paTV_lnaTV[i], s=100, cmap=cm.jet, edgecolors=None)
plt.colorbar()  # => ここでエラー発生
# ===================================
```

発生したエラーは以下

```
$ python make_corrCoef_data.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "make_corrCoef_data.py", line 58, in <module>
    plt.colorbar()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2114, in colorbar
    raise RuntimeError('No mappable was found to use for colorbar '
RuntimeError: No mappable was found to use for colorbar creation. First define a mappable such as an image (with imshow) or a contour set (with contourf).
```

Comment: `xx = plt.gca()`，`PCM = ax.get_children()[2]`，`plt.colorbar(PCM, ax=xx)`を`plt.colorbar()`の手前に挿入することで解決しました．参考URL:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23090791/matplotlib-colorbar-not-working-due-to-garbage-collection

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローでは[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)ができ、また推奨されています。少し待てば自分の回答を承認することもできますので、是非！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xx = plt.gca()`，`PCM = ax.get_children()[2]`，`plt.colorbar(PCM, ax=xx)`を`plt.colorbar()`の手前に挿入することで解決しました．参考URL:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23090791/matplotlib-colorbar-not-working-due-to-garbage-collection